# Google Spreadsheet function Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, spreadsheet

I am confused.

I have a spreadsheet in google with 2 tables.

I want to select data from a sheet named "Presseverteiler" where a value in one field equals the value that I enter in a second sheet named "Veröffentlichungen". The formula is inside the sheet "Veröffentlichungen".

My code is this

```
=IF(not(isblank(D2)) ; QUERY(Presseverteiler!$A$2:AZ;"SELECT F WHERE A="&D2&" LIMIT 1"); "")
```

D2 is a number in "Veröffentlichungen" that equals a number in "Presseverteiler" in column A.

If the numbers in column A are not sorted from A to Z (1 to 510 in my case), the query yields the result I want.

If the numbers in column A are in order though, the query gives the result I want plus the entry of line 2 which it puts ahead of the result I want.

If I want entry 223 it would give 2 and then 223. To make it more weird: I have many other columns. Depending on if I sort those by A-Z or Z-A some of them give me 1 result in the query, some give me 2 results. Some give me 1 result both ways.

For example if I sort "title" A-Z (contains Mr, Mrs, Dr.) I get 2 results, if I sort the same column Z-A I get one result.

If I order the column "publication" A-Z or Z-A I get one result.

Despite all that, why does the LIMIT 1 not work here? Even with that I get a #REF! error that the results can not be displayed because they would overwrite successive fields in the table.

Comment: Update: The Limit works but the first line is still selected. 
=QUERY(Presseverteiler!A1:Z1000;"SELECT F WHERE C='Energie'") yields 17 results. =QUERY(Presseverteiler!A1:Z1000;"SELECT F WHERE C='Energie' Limit 1") yields 2 results. Why is the first line always included though...?!

Comment: Thank you. I needed to specify that there are no headers with adding ;0 - that did it.